# ASP.NET MVC 4 IIS 7 Intranet Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, iis-7, web-deployment

I can't believe I am having such a hard time getting information on this. It seems almost all MS documentation is about deploying to Azure or in an "enterprise environment" etc.

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC 4 application that I want to deploy to IIS 7 on a server on our intranet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using [MsDeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).  It pretty much can do just about anything you need to deploy a website application to an IIS Server.